# Using a progress bar as a seek bar

Tags: iphone, progress-bar

How can a progress bar be used as a seek bar?

Comment: Can we do so? anyhow...
if yes then plzz help !!!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I just want to use it as a seek bar for my audio player...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an `UISlider`. Update its position periodically according to the playing position. Adjust your playing position whenever the slider calls its action.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a custom control for that.

There are tools to make this extremely easy. I don't want to do advertisement, but have a look at [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/). There you can create vector drawings with **paramters** like one for the current progress value. And you can have this drawing exported as **source code** which will create a UIView or UIControl subclass (at your choice) that has a property to set the current progress.

At least that's the way I'd do this.

Comment: I disagree that a custom control is the right choice.  There is a lot of subtlety to building custom controls.  Avoid it if possible.  Besides, the OP is likely trying to copy the iPod app UI and that uses a `UISlider` with a custom thumb image.  !00% standard.

Comment: I didn't mean a custom look of that control but to rather create a custom implementation. If a control doesn't fit your need you should rather create a custom copy than modify it. Might easily lead you into private api or compatibility issues. If the `UISlider` sufficient however, I totally agree that this is the way to go!